# log4j.properties - remove classname from output

Tags: java, log4j

I'd like to remove the timestamp and the classname from the output logging message for INFO using log4j logging. Right now, it appears that my program is not using the ConversionPattern layout line, because that line doesn't even refer to C which would be the Java class owning the logger object.

log4j.properties is loaded like this:

```
URL logConfigUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.properties");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(logConfigUrl);
```

Here is my log4j.properties file contents:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

right now, output looks like this:

14:24:17.387 [main] INFO  com.nim.tools.recontool.ReconTool

I want it to look like this:

[main] INFO

Comment: Maybe the *log4j.properties* file is not loaded correctly. I would first try to tweak some parameters like logging level and see if it has any effect.

Comment: I am pretty certain it's loaded correct but I will check

Comment: it's loaded like this so I doubt it could be improperly loaded otherwise it would throw an error                              URL logConfigUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.properties");
  PropertyConfigurator.configure(logConfigUrl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a wrong "log4j.properties" file has been loaded, as the output does not even match your configuration.

`URL logConfigUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.properties");`

loads the FIRST "log4j.properties" found on the class search paths. Some jars/dirs that contains "log4j.properties" could have been loaded ahead of your class. To verify which log4j.properties was loaded, you can print out the URL.

To configure your desirable output, you need:

`log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p: %m%n`